# ng-if in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to define different style by the value of a champ in ng-repeat, i try this :

```
<thead>
    <tr><th>#</th><th>Nom</th><th>Ville</th><th style="width: 50%;">Lignée</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="alternate1 in alternateViewText1.features | orderBy:'fiche.id*1'">
        <td>{{alternate1.fiche.id}}</td>
        <td ng-if="alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'yes'" style="color: green;">{{alternate1.properties.nom}}</td>
        <td ng-if="alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'no'" style="color: red;">{{alternate1.properties.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{alternate1.properties.ville}}</td>
        <td>{{alternate1.properties.lignee}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

it's not working (nothing show)

how can i define automatically a style with a particular value ?

Comment: Please provide fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bcKg6/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong value in your test

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/bcKg6/5/)

Replace `yes` by `actif` and `no` by `inactif`

Example :

```
<td ng-if="alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'actif'" style="color: green;">{{alternate1.properties.nom}}</td>
<td ng-if="alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'inactif'" style="color: red;">{{alternate1.properties.nom}}</td>
```

---

**PS:**

The answer of *ssilas777* is the best way to execute this switch of css class

Comment: Good that you found out 'actif' and 'inactif' should be used instead but I strongly believe ng-class should be the better option for this.

Comment: Yes i know and i say this in the comment of your answere ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class for particular style and use `ng-class` like this :

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bcKg6/8/)

css:

```
.green
 {
   color:green;
 }

.red
 {
   color:red;
 }
```

**html**:

```
<td data-ng-class="{'green' : alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'actif', 'red': alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'inactif'}">{{alternate1.properties.nom}}</td>
```

Comment: Why `data-ng-class` instead of `ng-class` ?

Comment: That is optional, both are same , in order to make the template valid HTML, we can use data-* attributes.

Comment: Why not combine into one `td`? The expression ca be something like: `ng-class="{'green' : alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'yes', 'red' : alternate1.properties.statut_activite == 'no' }"`.

Comment: This solution will output the name two times. To display it only once: `ng-class={ 'green': ...statut_activite == 'yes', 'red': ...statut_activite == 'no' }`.

Comment: ah, thats rit!, I didn't notice both are same values.

Comment: thaks for see my mistake and learn me a better way to made that

Comment: @JoDiii Check out the fiddle, I think thats what you are looking for